# Как загрузить русскоязычный шрифт в LibGDX?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, opengl, libgdx

Не понимаю, как в "LibGDX"-проекте загрузить кириллические символы при создании объекта класса `BitmapFont`. Казалось бы, я делаю строго по стандартной инструкции, но по какой-то причине ничего не получается. Такой код:

```
String textFontCharactersSet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;,{}\"´`'<>";
textFontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("engine-resources/noto-sans-regular.ttf"));
textFontGeneratorConfiguration = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
textFontGeneratorConfiguration.size = 12;
textFontGeneratorConfiguration.characters = textFontCharactersSet;
NOTO_FONT = textFontGenerator.generateFont(textFontGeneratorConfiguration);
textFontGenerator.dispose();
```

...подгружает шрифт, я вижу это по английским словам. Но что касается кириллических символов, то все они не отображаются. В качестве источника для шрифта я пробовала различные `.ttf`-файлы, далеко не только здешний "Noto Sans".

Comment: Возможно, проблема не в самом "LibGDX", а в кодировках то ли моей "Apache NetBeans", то ли самой Java'ы... Честно говоря, я не знаю, но пытаюсь сейчас разобраться с этой проблемой.

Comment: Посмотрите, в какой кодировке Ваш файл с этим кодом? Я не спец в Джаве, но возможно, что файл в ASCII, а код ожидает UTF-8, и символы маппятся не в те диапазоны.

Comment: Да, я, конечно, посмотрела - как ни странно, все файлы в UTF-8, так что дело не в них, а, скорее, в кодировке по умолчанию ОС. Но в целом как проблема стала понятной, так и вопрос отпал. В любом случае - спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `AssetManager`!
(А еще проверьте шрифт в `FontForge` на наличие кириллицы)

```
FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader generator = new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver);
assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, generator);
assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter fnt = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
fnt.fontFileName = "Путь до шрифта в assets";
assetManager.load("Название для дальнейшего получения", BitmapFont.class, fnt);
```